# Getting gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b"b'") when decompressing a received message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, compression, gzip, amazon-sqs

I have an html file named `75842.html` and I am compressing the file with gzip by doing the following:

```
with open('75842.html', 'rb') as f:
    body_compressed=gzip.compress(f.read())
```

`body_compressed` is a `<class 'bytes'>` object.

I cannot send bytes through SQS, the message body needs to be a string. So I'm defining `MessageBody=str(body_compressed)` when sending the file.

When reading the message on another server, I would like to decompress and save it using:

```
with open('75842_decompressed.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(gzip.decompress(str.encode(body)))
```

I get then the error message `gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b"b'")`. Probably because the file starts with a b'. However, I'm unsure how to solve it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str()` is a terrible idea. You end up tripling the size of the data, erasing the benefit of compression! Did you look at the lengths before and after `str()`?

What is the restriction on the data you can send? If you can only send printable characters, you can use [Base-64 or Base-85 encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html), which expand the data only by a few tens of percent, instead of a factor of there.